# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for http://a.b.c.d:9222

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I've read on https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps that you can debug in Chrome what is being done on Chromecast. However when i try

```
http://RECEIVER-IP-ADDRESS:9222
```

I verified the receiver-ip-address using the Chromecast application on my phone.

I get Chrome stating "This webpage is not available" and under the More button, it states "Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

Currently, my android application that I'm creating can be casted to Chromecast using the default media receiver application id.

By the way, my android application is successfully casting .jpg files as the user presses the app's next/prev buttons. I notice the default media receiver fades the current image away and displays the next image being casted. I'd like to ultimately have no fading and just show the next image that the user is requesting.

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your Chromecast as a developer device:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers
Its very easy to get the serial number wrong when you register the device in the Google Cast Developer Console, so double check that (taking a photo of the serial number will help to make the numbers clearer)
Restart the device to make sure it is configured correctly.

Comment: that worked. I just had to reboot the chromecast device. thank you.

Comment: Did not work for me... doubled checked serial, rebooted device.  As a matter of fact I'm seeing ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on a lot of sites I try to hit with Chrome in general, not just when trying to reach my chromecast IP.

Comment: We are rolling out a new build (31432) for chromecast that has a fix for the remote debugger.

Comment: Even I can't connect to the IP address of my registered Chromecast on the internal network on port 9222 through Chrome browser. @LeonNicholls, how can I check the build number of the Chromecast?

Comment: My Chromecast is still on firmware version 27946. Is there a way to force the firmware update?

Comment: @LeonNicholls ... still having the old version 27946. Any ETA for the new build please? Do we need to force firmware update? Thanks for he help.

Comment: Firmware version 31432 is rolling out now. Your chromecast should update itself automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the browser to speak or display the correct Serial Number rather than reading it manually off the device was what helped me. I was incorrectly reading an 'O' instead of a '0'. "Reading for Testing" does not mean that SDK console checks for Serial Number validity.